# I cannot set the pixel data of a PNG image

Tags: python, image-processing, png, python-imaging-library

I have a large set of images. Some are JPEG, some are PNG. For the PNGs, I am making a program to convert all transparent pixels into plain white. However, not only does it not work, some of the backgrounds change to random colors such as red and green. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, so here is my code:

```py
import os
from PIL import Image

files = os.listdir("/Users/Riley/PycharmProjects/myNN/logos")

for file in files:
    print(file)

    image = Image.open("/Users/Riley/PycharmProjects/myNN/logos/" + file)
    pixels = image.load()

    if image.mode == 'RGBA':
        print("RGBA")
        for x in range(image.size[0]):
            for y in range(image.size[1]):
                if pixels[x, y][3] < 1:
                    pixels[x, y] == (255, 255, 255, 1)
                    print(pixels[x, y])

        image = image.convert('RGB')
```

The `print(pixels[x, y])` is for troubleshooting. I get no error, yet it prints out random RGBA values despite just then setting it to (255, 255, 255, 1).
Thanks.

Comment: Interesting problem. Can you provide a sample image that demonstrates the problem? I tried running your code on a png I made in MS Paint and it seemed to work OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that. It is easier and faster to make a new image in white the same size as your one with transparency and paste the one with transparency on top and the white will show through.

```
from PIL import Image

# Open original with transparency
im = Image.open('image.png').convert('RGBA')

# Make white background same size
white = Image.new('RGB',im.size,color='white')

# Paste onto background
white.paste(im,mask=im)

# Save
white.save('result.png')
```

---

By the way, you can do that without writing any Python at all, just using **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

First, make an output directory where results will go:

```
mkdir output
```

Then flatten all your PNGs in one go onto white backgrounds:

```
magick mogrify -path output -background white -flatten /Users/Riley/PycharmProjects/myNN/logos/*png
```

If your **ImageMagick** is v6 or older, drop the `magick` and use:

```
mkdir output
mogrify -path output -background white -flatten /Users/Riley/PycharmProjects/myNN/logos/*png
```

Comment: I have added some extra info about an easier way to do it.

Comment: Okay so I haven't tested the terminal method, but I just tested the Python method and the problem is still there. It works for some images, but for others, the image goes mostly black with a bit of outline of the original image.

Comment: So it seems like this works when the alpha is 0 or 1, but not anywhere in between. I'm not sure what the solution is here.

Answer (score 1):

`pixels[x, y] == (255, 255, 255, 1)` is a comparison, not an assignment.

You might want to replace that statement with `pixels[x, y] = (255, 255, 255, 1)`.

Comment: @RileyFitzpatrick: Use a proper IDE, it'll prevent all trivial bugs.

Comment: ? I've never heard anything bad about PyCharm.

Comment: @Riley: If you weren't getting a warning on that line, you either have disabled too many warnings in PyCharm, or it's not a good IDE. A good IDE should give a warning when you compute something and discard its result.